# nginx: Address already in use

Tags: server, apache2, nginx

I have a low end self managed VPS that I maintain using Ubuntu 16.04 which I use to run a small site using nginx. There was a service interruption and after this was repaired the site was offline and I noticed that apache was listed as the webserver.

I logged in and the syslog shows

```
May 27 09:27:24 server systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
May 27 09:27:25 server nginx[3715]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
May 27 09:27:25 server nginx[3715]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)

deploy@server:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      322/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      189/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      598/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      322/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      517/master
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      189/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      517/master
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:789             0.0.0.0:*                           189/rpcbind
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           189/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 :::789                  :::*                                189/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                189/rpcbind
```

It appears that the ports originally served by Nginx are being taken by Apache and sshd?

What do I do next to get nginx back online?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303401/nginx-will-not-start-address-already-in-use

Comment: Apache is running. Stop apache and either remove or disable it and then then start nginx